# Open the same file in two instances .NET

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I want to use FSW to monitor when a file is opened and modified by the same instance of my application. I expect to trigger the watcher only when I save a file that is opened twice in the same application (our application). My issue is that this watcher is triggered even if I have just one instance of my application opened. How can I make the difference between saving (modifying) one file from another instance of application or saving the same file from the current instance of application?

I try using a collection, I try making `this.watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true` or `this.watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false` in different part of the program but nothing seems to solve my issue.

Here is my snippet code:

```
private void Load(string fileName)
{
    // Only watch seq files.
    this.watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);

    // Watch for changes in LastWrite times.
    this.watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

    this.watcher.Filter = "*.zzz";

    // Add event handlers.
    this.watcher.Changed += this.OnChanged;

    // Begin watching.
    this.watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    // opened file
}

// Define the event handlers.

private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = CustomMessageBox.ShowYesNoCancel(
                "The file has been modified by another instance.",
                "More app instances are opened!",
                "Overwrite",
                "Reload",
                "Save as",
                MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);

            if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                // Overwrite
                this.SaveSequence();
            }

            if (result == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
            {
                // Save as
            }

            if (result == MessageBoxResult.No)
            {
                // Reload file and lose changes
            }
        });

        // End watching.
        this.watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
    }

internal bool Save()
{
    /// some code

    this.File.Write(this.FilePath); //here is the moment when my watcher is triggered

    /// rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Why not disable events before you save and enable them after?

Comment: Simply enabling or disabling events would cause a race condition. The event itself lacks any info which could be used to distinguish the instance modifying the file. You also have the race condition purely from saving the file in multiple instances without some kind of synchronization in place.

Comment: You need to synchronize the file write e.g., using an [`EventWaitHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.eventwaithandle), then you can disable the FSW event until you set the `EventWaitHandle`.